# How to set JVM options for Tomcat instance executed from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jvm

I'm developing a Java/Spring/Hibernate application with eclipse which is deployed to tomcat and I'm having serious `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` issues.

I want to try to tweak the JVM settings used by the tomcat instance used by eclipse when launching the application.

Do you know how can I set the JVM tomcat parameters from eclipse? +1 if you know which files are affected.

I'm using tomcat 7.0.12, installed from a tar archive on a Linux machine.

I googled for hours but I couldn't find a working solution, TIA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]Under the 'server' view you will see the tomcat server instance listed.

Double click on it. This will open up a page in eclipse having server details. There is a link there called 'Open launch configuration'.

Click on that link and it will give you a dialog window. In that dialog window, under 'arguments' tab under vm arguments you can pass VM args

Comment: I was trying to add write the same..   I hope you have added tomcat in eclipse under 
window -> pref -> Server->runtime environment

Now while running your application, instead of choosing Run As -> Run on Server

choose  Run As -> Run Configutation,. select tomcat and provide your vm arguments under arguments.

Comment: I had to do:
{project name} -> Run As -> Run configurations -> Apache tomcat -> {name of my server instance} -> arguments -> VM arguments.

If I understand correctly this configuration is only used for running this particular project instance, so it should be preferable with respect to the @NimChimpsky reply.

Comment: There is no 'Open launch configuration' link. Update this and ill change to upvote.

Comment: This is where you would add the `--enable-preview` jvm argument to run an app compiled with jdk preview features. E.g. the preview features of JDK-14.

Answer (score 1):

specify the parameters that are you used by your catalina start up script, found here

```
tomcat_home/bin
```

it will use setenv script. Located in catalina_base. You can then add in there :

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xmx768m"
```

or for windows

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx768m
```

Comment: I see a lot of scripts in the tomcat/bin directory, amongst them startup.sh, catilina.sh, and tool-wrapper.sh. Do you know what is the script which needs to be modified or if/where all this is documented?

Comment: Anyway startup.sh seems to call catalina.sh, so it should be the right place where to add the config.

Comment: this will change it for eveything btw, not just eclipse, for just eclipse you probably want th eother answer. its catalina, which calls, setenv (which you create). sh or bat, not sure whther you are usign windows or *nix.